# How can I match any number OR string combined in regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a filter pattern that would match:

```
site39.social-buttons.com
site.social-buttons.com
123.social-buttons.com
```

However I cannot find anywhere how to use `any number or letter` in regex. I have found for `letters` only e.g `[a-g]`

```
(\.social\-buttons).com
```

What goes before the `\.` to match the above URLs?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any letter or number, what's the problem?

Comment: @aioobe I need to create a regex filter pattern for Google Analytics - I'm not writing this in a script/code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add numbers also in the character set:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```